# TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python

File "F:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\cracker.py", line 56
    if line.startswith('

My codes :

```
if system() == 'Linux':
  banner()
  f = open('/tmp/data.txt', 'rU')
  for line in f:
    if line.startswith('<li><a') == True:
      m = re.search(r'(<a href=")(.+[^>])(">)', line)
      i += 1
      local_name = '%s/file%d.txt' % (fout, i)
      print 'Retrieving...\t\t', site + m.group(2)
      try:  urllib.urlretrieve(site + m.group(2), local_name)
      except IOError:
        print '\n[%s] doesn\'t exist, create it first' % fout
        sys.exit()
    if line.startswith('<img') == True:
      m1 = re.search(r'(<a href=")(.+[^>])(">)', line)
      i += 1
      local_name = '%s/file%d.txt' % (fout, i)
      print 'Retrieving...\t\t', site + m1.group(2)
      try:  urllib.urlretrieve(site + m1.group(2), local_name)
      except IOError:
        print '\n[%s] doesn\'t exist, create it first' % fout
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: All you have to do is reformat your code so its consistent throughout the whole file

Comment: It is exactly what the error says. Use an editor of your choice to use either all tabs or all spaces.

Comment: File "F:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\cracker.py", line 56
    if line.startswith('<li><a') == 'True':
                                          ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: @MEhdiMEhdi we know the error and we're telling you how to fix it

Comment: Possible correction code

Answer (score 1):

Use **either** 4 spaces per indention, or one tab per indention (spaces per tabs can be set in your editor most likely). Mixing tabs and spaces is not allowed. You can fix this by hand (by going through and re-indenting everything) or your editor most likely has a tool that will do this for you.

Comment: @MEhdiMEhdi Don't ask us to write code for you.  Why don't YOU make the correction based on this answer?

Comment: Correction code? The solution has been given above multiple times: your code is incorrectly formatted. What editor are you using?